# How to stop chrome from capturing a tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webrtc, chromecast

I'm trying to build an chrome extension similar to the chromecast one.  I am using [chrome.tabCapture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabCapture) to successfully start a audio/video stream.  How do I stop the screen capture?  I want to have a stop button, but I am not sure what to call to stop it.  I can stop the LocalMediaStream, but the tab is still capturing and does not allow me to start a new capture without closing the tab.  Any suggestions or maybe an api page I may have missed?

Comment: From the docs: _"Capture is maintained across page navigations within the tab, and stops when the tab is closed, or the media stream is closed by the extension."_

Comment: Please add the code you use to "stop the LocalMediaStream"

Comment: Actullay I too have  the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715357/how-to-stop-the-capturing-mediastream-that-is-started-by-chrome-tabcapture-api-i , to stop the localMediastream, we have to use `stream.stop() ` but chrome throws an error like `Uncaught TypeError: stream.stop is not a function`

Answer (score 5):

Try `stream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();` to stop the screen capture. And to record the stream caught using chrome.tabCapture API , you could use [RecordRTC.js](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/blob/master/RecordRTC/RecordRTC.js)

```
var video_constraints = {
    mandatory: {
        chromeMediaSource: 'tab'
    }
};
var constraints = {
    audio: false,
    video: true,
    videoConstraints: video_constraints
};

chrome.tabCapture.capture(constraints, function(stream) {
    console.log(stream)
    var options = {
        type: 'video',
        mimeType : 'video/webm',
        // minimum time between pushing frames to Whammy (in milliseconds)
        frameInterval: 20,
        video: {
            width: 1280,
            height: 720
         },
         canvas: {
            width: 1280,
            height: 720
         }
     };
     var recordRTC = new RecordRTC(stream, options);
     recordRTC.startRecording();

    setTimeout(function(){
        recordRTC.stopRecording(function(videoURL) {
            stream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
            recordRTC.save();
         });
    },10*1000);
});
```

I hope the above code snippet would help you :)

Edit 1: corrected the RecordRTC initialization.

Comment: I formatted your code better (please learn how to use multi-line code on SO), but I still don't get your mediaRecorder remark, can you please explain that better?

Comment: Sorry , its RecordRTC.js which has to used to record to your stream got through chrome.tabCapture API