# How to stop the capturing mediastream that is started by chrome.tabCapture API in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tabs, google-api, record

I am developing a chrome extension and I use [chrome.tabCapture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabCapture) API to capture the stream from a tab of the chrome browser and to record the stream using [MediaStreamRecorder.js](https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder). I could stop the recording of the stream using mediaRecorder.stop() but that chrome.tabCapture API doesn't end. It continously sends the stream. I need to stop the chrome.tabCapture API running for the particular tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
stream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
```

To improve video quality, specify `videoConstraints` :

```
chrome.tabCapture.capture({
           videoConstraints: { mandatory: { maxWidth: 4000,
                                            maxHeight: 4000}
                              }}, callbackFunction);
```

Comment: Thanks for the above answer, but the resolution of the stream that we get through chrome.tabCapture API is very poor. Is there any way to improve that? I am also not sure whether the stream resolution is poor or the MediaStreamRecorder records the video in  a low resolution

Comment: @muthu I believe it's the way MediaStreamRecorder records the video. Unfortunately, since Chrome will not release full MediaRecorder functionality until release M49 (not without a development flag set), MediaStreamRecorder is left with using Whammy.js, which essentially takes frames from a video, puts them in canvas, and then gets the image from that. I think a lot of quality is lost in this process. If you look at the actual video output of the MediaStream straight to a video tag, it's quite good by default.